# SQL Server: Creating A Complex Calendar View For Employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I've been asked to turn a large Excel calendar into an SQL table structure so that we can include it's functionality in our internal application. To make it easier to explain, I've made a dummy example:

[image: Dummy Example Of Calendar[1]]

This is just one week, but it continues all the way to the far right with all the weeks of the year. You can see why this is a lot of manual labour. 
This calendar tells us that:

1. Everyone was off due to a national holiday on january first
2. Everyone was working in the office every day
3. James Adams was out of office, consulting at Customer A

We use colors and codes to make it a bit easier and quicker to interpret.
I've made a structure to mirror this in SQL Server:

[image: Calendar Structure In SQL]

**PlanningDay**

`PlanningDay` is the most important one.
It represents something special: like a holiday or consultancy task.
It's linked to an `Employee`, has a date value and represents AM or PM by a boolean (AM is true or false). A `PlanningDay` is always linked to one `PlanningDayDetail`. **It is important to know that, when no entry was found in table `PlanningDay`, the default of OF (Office) should be shown, except when it's a weekend).** Only the "exceptions" are registered.

**PlanningDayDetail**

Contains information about the general `PlanningDayType` (like Absent), and a more specific name and abbreviation, like Holiday and HOL.

**PlanningDayType**

Contains the general types available for usage, together with their corresponding color. All Absent types are marked purple for example, wheter it's a holiday or sickness.

The goal is to get this structure into a nice SSRS report. The report would have filters for the start and end date (so these must be dynamic) and a filter for Employee (for easy searches).

I would like to create a stored procedure which can then be used by the report, but I'm stuck on returning this overview. What I would like to return is 1 row for each `Employee`, 2 colomns (AM and PM) containing the `DisplayName` of the detail linked to the `PlanningDay` (if one is registered for that date AM / PM) for every single date that falls between then start and end date parameters. Basically, exactly the same as the Excel.

I've been looking at combining common table expressions for rendering all dates with pivoting to get the to show as columns, but haven't really gotten wiser yet. I hope you can help me out.

*EDIT:*

**Table Scripts**

```
CREATE TABLE [Mrd].[Employee]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_Mrd_Employee_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [Mrd].[PlanningDay]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_Mrd_PlanningDay_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [AM] BIT NOT NULL,
    [PlanningDayDealId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Mrd_PlanningDay_PlanningDayDealId_Mrd_PlanningDayDetail_Id]
    FOREIGN KEY ([PlanningDayDealId])
    REFERENCES [Mrd].[PlanningDayDetail] ([Id]),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Mrd_PlanningDay_EmployeeId_Mrd_Employee_Id]
    FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeId])
    REFERENCES [Mrd].[Employee] ([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [Mrd].[PlanningDayDetail]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_Mrd_PlanningDayDetail_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [PlanningDayTypeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Mrd_PlanningDayDetail_PlanningDayTypeId_Mrd_PlanningDayType_Id]
    FOREIGN KEY ([PlanningDayTypeId])
    REFERENCES [Mrd].[PlanningDayType] ([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [Mrd].[PlanningDayType]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_Mrd_PlanningDayType_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [ReportColor] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

**Dummy Data**

```
INSERT INTO [Mrd].[Employee] ([FirstName],[LastName])
VALUES
('Sandra','Cooper'),
('James','Adams'),
('Martha','Reid');

INSERT INTO [Mrd].[PlanningDayType] ([Name],[ReportColor])
VALUES 
('Absent','#8b4789'),
('Consultancy','#c7c700');

INSERT INTO [Mrd].[PlanningDayDetail] ([PlanningDayTypeId],[Name],[DisplayName])
VALUES 
(1,'New Year','HOL'),
(2,'Customer A','C-A');

INSERT INTO [Mrd].[PlanningDay] ([EmployeeId],[Date],[AM],[PlanningDayDealId])
VALUES 
(1,'2018-01-01',1,1),
(1,'2018-01-01',0,1),
(2,'2018-01-01',1,1),
(2,'2018-01-01',0,1),
(3,'2018-01-01',1,1),
(3,'2018-01-01',0,1),
(2,'2018-01-03',1,2),
(2,'2018-01-03',0,2),
(2,'2018-01-04',1,2),
(2,'2018-01-04',0,2),
(2,'2018-01-05',1,2);
```

**Expected Outcome** (if it's possible like this)

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Employee    | 2018-01-01 AM | 2018-01-01 PM | 2018-01-02 AM | 2018-01-02 PM | 2018-01-03 AM | 2018-01-03 PM |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Sandra Cooper | HOL           | HOL           | OF            | OF            | OF            | OF            |
| James Adams   | HOL           | HOL           | OF            | OF            | C-A           | C-A           |
| Martha Reid   | HOL           | HOL           | OF            | OF            | OF            | OF            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**What I've Tried**

Before even starting with the report, I'm trying to create a query / stored procedure that returns 2 record for every day per employee, 1 record presenting AM and the other the PM part of that day for one employee.

My latest try includes a CTE to create a range of dates:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate   DATE = '2018-01-31';


WITH AllDays AS
    (SELECT @StartDate AS [Day]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Day])
     FROM AllDays
      WHERE [Day] < @EndDate)

SELECT ad.[Day] AS 'Date', pd.[AM], pdd.[DisplayName], e.[FirstName] + ' ' + e.[LastName] AS 'Employee'
FROM AllDays ad
LEFT JOIN [Mrd].[PlanningDay] pd
ON ad.[Day] = pd.[Date]
LEFT JOIN [Mrd].[PlanningDayDetail] pdd
ON pd.[PlanningDayDealId] = pdd.[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Mrd].[PlanningDayType] pdt
ON pdd.[PlanningDayTypeId] = pdt.[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Mrd].[Employee] e
ON pd.[EmployeeId] = e.[Id]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Incorrect Result**

```
+------------+------+-------------+---------------+
|    Date    |  AM  | DisplayName |   Employee    |
+------------+------+-------------+---------------+
| 2018-01-01 | 1    | HOL         | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-01 | 0    | HOL         | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-01 | 1    | HOL         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-01 | 0    | HOL         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-01 | 1    | HOL         | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-01 | 0    | HOL         | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-02 | NULL | NULL        | NULL          |
| 2018-01-03 | 1    | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-03 | 0    | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-04 | 1    | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-04 | 0    | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-05 | 1    | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-06 | NULL | NULL        | NULL          |
| 2018-01-07 | NULL | NULL        | NULL          |
+------------+------+-------------+---------------+
```

This gives me the correct results for the first of January, because it's a holliday and there are `PlanningDays` registered for every `Employee`. What I am trying to achieve in the first place is this (sorry for the long list):

**Required Result**

```
+------------+----+-------------+---------------+
|    Date    | AM | DisplayName |   Employee    |
+------------+----+-------------+---------------+
| 2018-01-01 |  1 | HOL         | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-01 |  0 | HOL         | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-01 |  1 | HOL         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-01 |  0 | HOL         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-01 |  1 | HOL         | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-01 |  0 | HOL         | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-02 |  1 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-02 |  0 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-02 |  1 | OF          | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-02 |  0 | OF          | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-02 |  1 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-02 |  0 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-03 |  1 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-03 |  0 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-03 |  1 | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-03 |  0 | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-03 |  1 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-03 |  0 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-04 |  1 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-04 |  0 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-04 |  1 | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-04 |  0 | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-04 |  1 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-04 |  0 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-05 |  1 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-05 |  0 | OF          | Sandra Cooper |
| 2018-01-05 |  1 | C-A         | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-05 |  0 | OF          | James Adams   |
| 2018-01-05 |  1 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
| 2018-01-05 |  0 | OF          | Martha Reid   |
+------------+----+-------------+---------------+
```

Notice how on the second of January, instead of NULL, I want to render OF for every single Employee. On the third of January, I want to render OF (Office) as default for Sandra and Martha, but James has a special `PlanningDay` registered for Consulting at Customer A, etc ... Now I know I can transform NULLS to a default value with COALESCE, but before I can do that, I need NULLS for every single Employee where no `PlanningDay` is registered.

If this is even achievable, I could then try to pivot this result into the expected end result (see above).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @J.M I believe you are asking a mini project to be implemented in a single question?

Comment: @SathiyaKumar this in't a mini project. This is a pretty big task.

Comment: Thanks for the link Sean. I've added my table scripts and the same dummy data to use.

Comment: What have you tried already? And you are going to need a calendar table or a tally table. Something to return a row for each day you want in the output.

Comment: I've added what I am currently trying. Please don't get me wrong, I don't want anyone to create all of this for me. All I need is a bit of guidance in what I am doing. I am still rather new to SQL and programming in general, so if what I am trying to achieve here is uther nonsense, feel free to tell me :) I have also edited my Dummy data to fix some errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were pretty close to the solution. I just rejigged the initial joins to use **CROSS JOIN** which will generate a row for each combination of Day, AM/PM and Employee. Once you have that generated, the existing **LEFT JOIN**s will slot in your planning days and you can replace the NULL's with the default values you specified in your question.

You can try this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00f88/13)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate   DATE = '2018-01-31';

WITH AllDays AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Day]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Day])
    FROM
        AllDays
    WHERE 
        [Day] < @EndDate
    )
SELECT
    ad.[Day] AS 'Date'
,   Period.[AM]
,   pdd.[DisplayName]
,   e.[FirstName] + ' ' + e.[LastName] AS 'Employee'
FROM
    AllDays ad
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT CAST( 0 AS BIT ) AS [AM] UNION ALL SELECT CAST( 1 AS BIT )) AS Period
CROSS JOIN
    [Employee] e
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [PlanningDay] pd ON (
        pd.[Date] = ad.[Day]
    AND pd.EmployeeId = e.[Id]
    AND pd.[AM] = Period.[AM]
    )
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [PlanningDayDetail] pdd ON (pdd.[Id] = pd.[PlanningDayDealId])
LEFT OUTER JOIN
[PlanningDayType] pdt ON (pdt.[Id] = pdd.[PlanningDayTypeId])
ORDER BY
    [Date], [Employee], [AM]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nik, this did the job! I had read about cross joins before, but it didn't pop into mind during my struggle :-) I can start working with this for a sample report already. Do you happen to know a way to pivot this data like displayed in the Expected Outcome section of my question? Or do you think that's a bit overkill or not even possible with the AM / PM requirements? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You really want to do the pivot in the SSRS report. You can do it in SQL, but it's more rigid in terms of knowing the date range in advance. Even if you do it with dynamic SQL, the report engine has a hard time with stuff like that. If you do it in the SSRS Matrix, it's fairly easy to get the correct output.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot in the coming days. Big thanks again for the constructive feedback! I'll sleep well again tonight :-)